# Non-linear Fit with Independent Variable as Integral Bound

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use *Matlab* to fit a dataset (with vectors *x* and *y*) to a function *x(y)*, in which *y* appears as the upper bound of an integral and the fitting parameter is the lower bound.

I have defined two functions:

```
p = @(x,a) sqrt((1 - x.^2 / a.^2).^(-2) - 1)
x = @(y, a, y0, x0) quad(@(x) 1 ./ p(x,a), y0, y) + x0
```

My data points are stored in a dataset called `data`.

I am now trying to call:

```
nlinfit(data.y, data.x, @(c, y) x(y, 0.0027, c(1), 0.001), 0.00001)
```

However, the following error is generated:

```
Error using nlinfit (line 142)
Error evaluating model function '@(c,y)x(y,0.0027,c(1),0.001)'.
Caused by:
    Error using quad (line 66)
    The limits of integration must be scalars.
```

How can I convince *Matlab* to do a non-linear fit for `y0`?

I am new to working with *Matlab*. However, I have already solved this problem in *Mathematica* with just three lines, so I suppose I am making a rather simple error...

Comment: nlinfit will pass vectors, i.e. multiple inputs to your function. Write it in such a way that it can accept vectors (quad for example can handle vectors).

Comment: @AndreasH., thank you for your help! I was not aware of this characteristic of `nlinfit`'s behaviour. Replacing my model function with a call of `arrayfun` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: seems ok to me. I just noticed a typo in my comment (I meant "can't" not "can"!). Sorry for the confusion!